# Como fazer Tyscript ler um arquivo JSON que se encontra no disco?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arquivo, typescript

Tenho um código em TypeScript (NodeJS-10.6.0) e preciso criar uma variável que vai recuperar o conteúdo de um arquivo JSON.

Ja tentei importar o conteúdo do arquivo das seguintes maneiras:

```
 1. import { orderPayload } = require('../../events/qa/myfile.json');
 2. import { orderPayload } = '../../events/qa/myfile.json';
 3. const orderPayload: Order = require ('../../events/qa/myfile.json');
 4. const orderPayload= require ('../../events/qa/myfile.json');
```

O TSlint mostra os seguintes errors:

```
 1. TS1141 - String Literal expected, Required statement not part of a import statement (no-var-required)
 2. String Literal expected
 3. Required statement not part of a import statement (no-var-required)
 4. Required statement not part of a import statement (no-var-required)
```

Existe alguma maneira de importar o conteúdo desse arquivo JSON para a variável `orderPayload` sem precisar usar o módulo FS file system do NodeJs?

Comment: o arquivo `JSON` possui uma `key` com o nome `orderPayload`?

Comment: Não. Possui somente 2 chaves 'metadata' e 'payload'.

Comment: Uma dúvida: qual o problema de usar o FS? Achava que era a forma mais comum de carregar arquivos. Aliás, já que é Node deve ter biblioteca pronta pra carregar JSON que use o FS internamente, se você só quiser um código mais limpo.

Answer (score 1):

Você não pode simplesmente dar import em um arquivo JSON sem os devidos exports.

Faça o seguinte:

**myfile.json**

```
export const orderPayload  = {...}
```

E depois você pode fazer `import { orderPayload } from '../../events/qa/myfile.json';`

Comment: Eu consigo rodar: `const orderPayload = require('.teste.json');`

Comment: É ... eu colei errado. Seria `import { orderPayload } from '../../events/qa/myfile.json';` ou `const orderPayload = require('../../events/qa/myfile.json');`

Comment: Na verdade não é necessário exporta os objetos, se você importar o .json escolhendo quais itens quer ira funcionar perfeitamente. O consign é prova disso ele carrega os .json sem exporta los. Eu constumo importar varios .json de configurações de banco, cloud, etc.

Comment: O consign usa `fs` meu jovem. O autor da pergunta disse: sem utilizar o fs.... [Veja](https://github.com/jarradseers/consign/blob/develop/lib/consign.js)